# How to Drop a Duplicates Column in dataframe while retaining the Unique Column including the only one column among duplicates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to drop the duplicate column while retaining only the unique columns and only one column among the duplicates after joining.

For Example:
Duplicate DataFrame

```
root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- loc: string (nullable = true)
|-- sal: string (nullable = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- loc: string (nullable = true)
|-- sal: string (nullable = true)


After removing duplicates, the output should be

root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- loc: string (nullable = true)
|-- sal: string (nullable = true)
```

Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: You can try dropping the columns before joining on one of the dataframes. Or you can use the duplicate columns to perform the join, in this case only one will be left afterwards.

Comment: I tried this approach. I am trying to develop a generic code and don't want to handcode columns around the Data Frame.

Answer (score 1):

As Shaido already commented above stating that you should drop all the columns that are not used for join as it would be difficult after you join them. (for example if loc and sal are not used in join then)

```
df2.drop("loc", "sal")
```

or

```
df1.drop("loc", "sal")
```

If you are using column names (for example id and name) in the join then do as

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("id", "name"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, if you go for generic approach, then below code may be help you. Here you no need to mention the duplicate column names.

1. First create a implicit class (Better design approach)

   ```
   implicit class DataFrameOperations(df: DataFrame) {
     def dropDuplicateCols(rmvDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
       val cols = df.columns.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).filter(_._2 > 1).keySet.toSeq

       @tailrec def deleteCol(df: DataFrame, cols: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
         if (cols.size == 0) df else deleteCol(df.drop(rmvDF(cols.head)), cols.tail)
       }
       deleteCol(df, cols)
     }
   }
   ```
2. To call the method you can use below one

   ```
   val dupDF = rdd1.join(rdd2,"id").dropDuplicateCols(rdd1)
   ```

Comment: Thanks Neel, I was looking for an approach similar to this. This works for me.

Answer (score -4):

```
//For exemple
val dataFrame = sparkSession.sql("SELECT .....")
dataFrame .distinct() //since 2.0.0
//or
dataFrame.dropDuplicates()
//or
dataFrame.dropDuplicates(colNames)
```

Comment: these suggestions is for rows, not for columns